# VMWARE ESXi and SSD - ext4 trim discard

Tags: ssd, esxi, trim

I'm running ESXi 5.5 box with Debian as guest OS. and I'm planning to use SSD disk(with ext4) for MySQL database for performance reasons.

ESXi recognizes that I'm using SSD disk.

But how to let know guest OS that it is SSD disk? Or it isn't needed?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be needed.  What the guest OS "sees" is the virtual file system provided by the hypervisor, vice the underlying hardware.